# How about a "promised-bounty" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, bounty

I don't know if this has been discussed before on some other site.

Often I feel like putting a bounty on questions (usually my own) questions, because they are based on optimisation and better solutions could be found any time. Then I often decide not to, because it is possible that no solution comes up in a single week, or that not enough people saw it.

**Can we have a tag named "promised-bounty" to indicate to all users that a person has promised a specified bounty, if ever an answer meets certain conditions?**

This would especially be useful on newer sites (like Puzzling SE, and maybe even newer than that), where people don't have too much rep to waste, and readership of questions is low.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Codegolf.SE has a [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5243/20260) to advertise all the conditional bounties with no deadlines. We could set up the same.

Comment: If your answer got up-voted, why is my question down-voted?

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code I suspect people just didn't like making it a tag.

Comment: Is anyone going to make the post? Or should I make it? (I hope I won't get down-voted)

Comment: @ghosts_in_the_code Don't worry too much about down-votes on meta. [Downvotes on meta are different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites)

Answer (score 3):

This is not the purpose of tags.

> A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories.
>   (https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score -4):

It sounds to me like this should be a feature request:  Something like an open-ended bounty, where it doesn't expire and can be awarded at any time.

There are probably specific reasons why bounties weren't designed that way, so your chances of getting it implemented are probably slim.  It makes more sense to me to alter the way bounties are assigned rather than create a tag.