# List of bounties with no deadlines

Tags: discussion, faq, bounty

*This is a list of unofficial, deadline-less (hence not searchable) bounties offered by users on various challenges on the main site.*

**Disclaimer**: There is no guarantee that the user will award the bounty for you in case you fulfill its requirement. Especially if the user isn't an active member anymore. The only guarantee is his/her written word.

### Update guidelines:

- You can add a missing entry to one of the lists. If the bounty offerer has been seen in the past 60 days (based on his/her profile page) choose the first (active members) list otherwise the second (passive members) list.
- If a bounty is awarded delete it from its list.
- If the offerer of a bounty in the active list become passive move the entry to do passive list.
- An entry can be moved back to the active list from the passive one **only by the offerer** (to decrease maintenance work).

### Offered bounties from active members (sorted by amount):

- **2750 reputation** (500 from **[Sny Smartie](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/87878/)**, 500 from **[GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421)**,
  500 from **[Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208)**, 500 from **[question_asker](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17250)**, 500 from **[CrSb0001](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/86115/crsb0001)**, 250 from **[Z Dailey](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/19731)**)

  - [Unsolved Mysteries: Kryptos](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25931) - provide a credible solution for Part 4

---

- **1500 reputation** (500 from **[Lukas Rotter](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37714/lukas-rotter)**, 500 from **[codewarrior0](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/83349/codewarrior0)**, 500 from **[CrSb0001](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/86115/crsb0001)**)

  - [Noita Eye Glyphs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119923/noita-eye-glyphs)

---

- **1000 reputation** (500 from **[GentlePurpleRain](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4421)**
  and 500 from **[Alconja](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5208)**)

  - [Unsolved Mysteries: Magic Square of Squares](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23944) - provide a valid solution or prove that no solution exists

---

- **500 reputation** from **[ghosts_in_the_code](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/4269)**

  - [Variant of lion and 100 zebras](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9155) - submit a formal proof that solves the puzzle either way
  - [Rigged casino that prevents pairs](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9875) - do better than 17 (250 rep for proving 17 optimal)
  - [Maximize 'chains' in a Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10769) - do better than 27 (250 rep for proving 27 optimal)

---

- **500 reputation** from **[Rewan Demontay](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/57521/rewan-demontay)**

  - [Find My Mission For Me](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81458/find-my-mission-for-me) - For solving my nearly three-year-old puzzle.

---

- **250 reputation** from **[ACB](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/81979/acb)**

  - [A fairy tale in a golden toy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/98753/81979)

---

- **75 reputation** from [CrSb0001](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/86115/crsb0001)

  - [My smol boi puzzle! :3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122682/my-smol-boi-puzzle-3) - For solving my thrid puzzle

### Offered bounties from passive members (sorted by amount):

- **200 reputation** from **[Anachor](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/15544)**

  - [Nine gangsters and a gold bar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19870) - provide a full proof that 17 pieces cannot be achieved (or a solution with 17 pieces)

**P.S.** This practice is followed on [Code Golf SE](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadlines) and was approved on [Puzzling Meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4377/how-about-a-promised-bounty-tag/) also (6 upvotes, no downvotes on @xnor 's answer as of today).

Comment: Is there any etiquette recommended for notifying bounty offerers of solutions?

Comment: @Hackiisan I would say tagging the bounty offerer in a comment either here or on the answer deserving of a bounty would be the best way. Just let them know you've found a bounty-worthy solution and hopefully they'll respond. Another option would be to tag them in chat.

Comment: How does a user add a bounty for an unlimited time?

Comment: @downvote Just edit this post and add a line to your own post. You don't actually add a bounty, you just promise that you will create and give a bounty if and when a satisfactory answer emerges.