# What's the etiquette for notifying deadline-less bounty offerers of solutions?

Tags: discussion, bounty

This is a spinoff question from [a previous meta question on bounties with no deadlines](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadlines). Is there any etiquette recommended for this situation?

I was thinking perhaps answering the aforementioned meta question while tagging the question asker. This way we can also keep track of the progress of these particular bounties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pinging them with a comment somewhere should normally suffice. You can also ping any editor on a post, so if someone edited their extended bounty into the main post, you can comment there, too.

Though this is less likely to happen, if they're active in chat, pinging them there definitely works, too.

Comment: Just to clarify: I originally didn't know what "pinging" meant, but [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) helped.